# Scaling a sequential program into chain of queues

Tags: python, amazon-sqs

I am trying to scale an export system that works in the following steps:

- Fetch a large number of records from a MySQL database. Each record is a person with an address and a product they want.
- Make an external API call to verify address information for each of them.
- Make an internal API call to get store and price information about the product on each record.
- Assign identifiers to each record in a specific format, which is different for each export.
- Dump all the data into a file, zip it and email it.

As of now all of this happens in one monolithic python script which is starting to show its age. As the number of records being exported at a time has grown by about 10x, the script takes a lot of memory and whole export process is slow because all the steps are blocking and sequential.

In order to speed up the process and make it scalable I want to distribute the work into a chain of SQS queues. This is quite straightforward for the first 4 steps:

- Selector queue - takes a request, decides which records will be exported. Creates a msg for each of them in the verifier queue with `export_id` and `record_id`.
- Verifier queue - takes the id of the record, makes the API call to verify its address. Creates a msg in the price queue with `export_id` and `record_id`.
- Price queue - takes the id of a record, makes the API call to get prices and attaches it to the record. Creates a msg in the assigner queue with `export_id` and `record_id`.
- Assigner queue - takes the id of a record, assigns it the sequential export ID. Creates a msg in the dumper queue with `export_id` and `record_id`.
- Dumper queue - ???

This is all fine and dandy till now. Work is parallelized and we can add more workers to whichever step needs them the most.

I'm stumped by how to add the last step in the process?

Till now all the queues have been (suitably) dumb. They get a msg, perform an action and pass it on. In the current script, by the time we reach the last step, the program can be certain that all previous steps are complete for all the records and it is time to dump the information. How should I replicate this in the distributed case?

Here are the options I could think of:

- <del>The dumper queue just saves it's incoming msgs in a DB table till it gets a msg flagged "FINAL" and then it dumps all msgs of that `export_id`. This makes the final msg a single point of failure.</del> If multiple exports are being processed at the same time, order of msgs is not guaranteed so deciding which msg is final is prone to failure.
- Pass an `expected_total` and `count` in each step and the dumper queue waits till it gets enough msgs. This would cause the dumper queue to get blocked and other exports will have to wait till all msgs of a previously started export are received. Will also have to deal with possibly infinite wait time in some way if msgs get lost.

None of the above options seem good enough. What other options do I have?

At a high level, consistency is more important than availability in this problem. So the exported files can arrive late, but they should be correct.

**Msg Delay Reasons**

As asked in the comments:

- Internal/External API response times may vary. Hard to quantify.
- If multiple exports are being processed at the same time, msgs from one export may get lagged behind or be received in a mixed sequence in queues down the line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do the following:

- Assigner

  - Reads from the assigner queue and assigns the proper ids
  - Packs the data in bulks and uploads them to S3.
  - Sends the path to S3  to the Dumper queue
- Dumper reads the bulks and dumps them to DB in bulks

Comment: The dumper has to send an email with all the data for an export. How does it know it has all the data for a particular export? And that there will be no further msgs for that export?

Comment: You should either create a time window (TTL?), mark message as last or mix them and send data that was not completed to some grave yard. What is the nature of this app ? More details will help

Comment: To reduce the graveyard size and the complexity you can also handle messages that are older than x seconds or minutes so 99.9% of the messages will be handled in a single try - this can reduce code complexity and caching

Comment: TTL and flagging the last msg are definitely good suggestions. What particular details would you like me to add to the question?

Comment: Something that will let me understand why are messages delayed. What is the common length of a delay normally and when some component goes bad. In addition you can add logical rules like dont dump anything with less than one message..

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: So you can calculate the upper bound of the reasonable time and have a TTL of something like 15 minutes  - calc it based on http timeouts. If a new message has not arrived then you can send it to the grave yard or to the final destination (based on expected_count). Anyway I would monitor the grave yard to make sure that things work as expected at all times

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a cache instead of a queue.